# same command with output X in main body and Y in footnote

Tags: macros, fun

In reference to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145964/12277), I would like to ask whether there could be a command that produces the output X when issued in the body of a text, but the output Y when issued in any sort of footnote.

Example:

`This is a nice sentence says Mister \funnycommand.\footnote{This is a nice footnote says Mister \funnycommand.}`

Output:

> This is a nice sentence says Mister X.*1
>
> ==============
>
> *1 This is a nice footnote says Mister Y.

Comment: Hi! Can I ask what exactly do you need it for?

Comment: @tohecz : Of course. I often use my own command `\BookTitle` to quote booktitles. In the footnote, then, I usually quote the title abbreviated using `\BookTitleAbb`. I now recognised that I sometimes did not use the abbreviated form in the footnotes and thought that if there could be one single command that determines on its own whether to use abbreviated or not, I could maintain the coherence of my document easier. And since there is, e.g., biblatex 's `smartcite`-command, which behaves differently depending on whether it is in the main body or in the footnotes, I thought it might be easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you don't use packages that change footnote management:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{scrartcl} % works also with Koma-Script classes
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifinfootnote
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{scr@saved@footnotetext}
  {\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}}
  {\patchcmd{\scr@saved@footnotetext}}
  {\reset@font}
  {\reset@font\infootnotetrue}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@mpfootnotetext}
  {\reset@font}
  {\reset@font\infootnotetrue}
  {}{}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\funnycommand}{\ifinfootnote Y\else X\fi}

\textheight=4cm % just for the example

\begin{document}
This is a nice sentence says
Mister \funnycommand.\footnote{This is a nice footnote
says Mister \funnycommand.} Again, \funnycommand

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\funnycommand\footnote{\funnycommand}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***NOTE*** Added compatibility with Koma-Script classes

Comment: nice way! Of course, now I have to admit that I indeed use `scrbook`/`scrartcl` and `hyperref` to which your solution does not seem to be compatible. I also use `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}\raggedbottom` and `csquotes` but they seem to be fine with your solution. Two questions: 1) any way to adjust this to KOMA and `hyperref`? 2) Any way to use something of the `\smartcite`-command from `biblatex`? I am asking because this works well with all packages I am loading or is it too difficult to dig u the code? So that we do not have to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @ClintEastwood Sorry, but a solution to a not clearly stated problem is impossible. I added support for Koma-Script

Comment: i underestimated the issue. I thought it would be easier and had less implications on other packages. I will have a look at how hyperref redefines footnotes.

Answer (score 4):

A hack ---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\let\realfootnote=\footnote
\newif\ifinfootnote\infootnotefalse
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{{\infootnotetrue\realfootnote{#1}}} %double grouping!
\newcommand{\funnycommand}{\ifinfootnote Y\else X\fi}
\begin{document}
  This is a nice sentence says 
  Mister \funnycommand.\footnote{This is a nice footnote 
  says Mister \funnycommand.} Again, \funnycommand
\end{document}
```

you have to modify it to take into account the optional parameter of `\footnote` if you need it.

Comment: +1, just two remarks: Putting `\infootnotetrue` inside `\footnote{...}` would prevent the necessity of grouping. And if you group, it's in general preferred to use `\begingroup...\endgroup` instead of `{...}` of `\bgroup...\egroup`.