# Detect whether I'm in a \footnote?

Tags: footnotes, conditionals

How do I detect whether I'm in a `\footnote` environment or not?

Comment: Do you use any special footnote packages? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows your use-case.

Comment: I think this may be rather difficult to do. `Biblatex` does it, but it involves many lines of code patching various footnote commands (which vary depending on class and package loaded). You could, if you feel strong, borrow/steal that code. It's around lines 134-197 of biblatex2.sty. Or, if you load `biblatex` anyway you could piggy-back on its commands.

Comment: Stricly speaking, `\footnote` is just a macro, not an environment.

Comment: Does [Same command with output X in main body and Y in footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/) help?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just `\def\infootnote` to `T` or `F`.  If you needed to branch on that basis, you could perform `\if T\infootnote TRUE code\else FALSE code\fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\thefootnote]{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \gdef\infootnote{T}%
  \svfootnote[#1]{#2\gdef\infootnote{F}}%
}
\gdef\infootnote{F}
\textheight 1in
\begin{document}
Footnote status: \infootnote.  Now entering a footnote%
\footnote{The status now: \infootnote.  Done.}
Continuing with status: \infootnote.  Again.
\footnote{The status now: \infootnote.  Done.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Define a conditional `\iffootnote` and redefine `\footnote` so that it makes `\iffootnote` come out true inside its parameter, but false outside. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iffootnote
\let\Footnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{\begingroup\footnotetrue\Footnote{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}

foo\footnote{a\iffootnote yes\else no\fi}

bar \iffootnote yes\else no\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\footnote` macro defined by the LaTeX kernel also accepts an optional argument.

Comment: This is just the idea.