# Page-n-footnote-number in index, with texindy

Tags: footnotes, xindy

I want my index to show those items appearing within a footnote as page-number plus the footnote symbol, for instance, `137n7` for something in footnote 7 on page 137. Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55460/3935, I use a special indexing command within footnotes that works correctly when the `.idx` file is processed with MakeIndex. The command depends on the meaning (special to MakeIndex) of a pipe within an `\index` command, to modify the page number of an indexed item.

But I am processing my index with `texindy`, not MakeIndex, for foreign-language support, and with `texindy` those special index entries are ignored. The `xindy` man page explains:

> For raw index entries in LaTeX syntax, `\index{aaa|bbb}` is interpreted differently. For MakeIndex `bbb` is markup that is output as a LaTeX tag for this page number. For `xindy`, this is a location attribute, an abstract identifier that will be later associated with markup that should be output for that attribute.

I do not understand how to handle `xindy` location attributes to get the original effect. It seems to me that because `\footnote` has to be appended, this is not simple markup that can be done outside of the original to-be-indexed file itself. Xindy markup syntax is described [here on the Xindy documentation site](http://www.xindy.org/doc/manual-3.html#ss3.2).

**MWE**:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\pageandfn}[2]{#2n#1}    % format as <page>n<footnotemark>
\newcommand{\indexfn}[1]{\index{#1@ #1|pageandfn{\thefootnote}}}

\begin{document}
Some text here.%
\footnote{Plain footnote\index{footnote, \texttt{\textbackslash index}}.} %

More text here.\footnote{%
Specially indexed footnote\indexfn{footnote, \texttt{\textbackslash indexfn}}.
}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

**Text after compiling once**:

[image: Text proper]

[image: Footnotes]

**Here are the contents of the `.idx` file**:

```
\indexentry{footnote, \texttt  {\textbackslash index}}{1}
\indexentry{footnote, \texttt  {\textbackslash indexfn}@ footnote, \texttt  {\textbackslash indexfn}|pageandfn{2}}{1}
```

**Processed with MakeIndex** and then compiled again:

[image: Index when processed with MakeIndex]

**Processed with `texindy`** and then compiled again:

[image: Index when processed with <code>texindy</code>]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing just a page number to the index file, one can write a list of the page number and the footnote number, setting the latter to 0 if the item to be indexed is not in a footnote.

Here is how the idea applies to your MWE. It also uses hyperref for further convenience.

**mwe-style.xdy**:

```
;; make xindy and hyperindex work together
;; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80300/how-can-i-convince-hyperref-and-xindy-to-play-together-nicely
;; (the comment by michal.h21)
;; (markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
;; now taken care of by attribute formatloc


(define-attributes (("formatloc")) )
(markup-locref :attr "formatloc" :open "\formatloc{" :close "}")


(define-location-class "pagefn" :var
     ("arabic-numbers" :sep " "  "arabic-numbers"))

(define-location-class-order ("pagefn"))

;; End
```

**mwe.tex**:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mwe-style]

% test to detect we are in a footnote;
% taken from
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171681/detect-whether-im-in-a-footnote/
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\thefootnote]{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \gdef\infootnote{T}%
  \svfootnote[#1]{#2\gdef\infootnote{F}}%
}
\gdef\infootnote{F}

% write the footnote number if we're in one
% and 0 otherwise
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fnind}{\if T\infootnote
\@currentlabel%
\else 0\fi%
}
\makeatother


% \formatlocc formats the locations as given in the .ind index files
% \formatloc is a wrapper for \formatlocc to permit braces
\newcommand{\formatloc}[1]{\formatlocc #1}
\def\formatlocc #1 #2{%
\ifnumequal{#2}{0}{\hyperpage{#1}}{\hyperpage{#1}n#2}%
}



% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers/20910#20910
\makeatletter
\let\@indexfn\@index
\patchcmd{\@indexfn}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\thepage\space\fnind}{}{}
\let\xindexfn\index
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\newcommand{\indexfn}[2][\imki@jobname]{\xindexfn[#1]{#2|formatloc}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
Some text here.%
\footnote{Plain footnote\index{footnote, \texttt{\textbackslash index}}.} %

More text here.\footnote{%
Specially indexed footnote\indexfn{footnote, \texttt{\textbackslash indexfn}}.
}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Compile using the -shell-escape flag, or run texindy by hand.