# Sorting problem with index entries for footnotes as page-n-footnote

Tags: makeindex

I am working on an index for a large scientific manuscript. I would like to have index entries occurring as footnotes to be in the index as page-n-footnote. Courtesy of brannerchinese's code in this forum I have nearly got the problem solved. The issue is that the footnoted indices are not properly sorted. The "Tiger" entry in the index is output as

> Tiger, i, 1    Tiger, in1

when it should be

> Tiger, i, in1, 1

The .idx entries are of the form

```
\indexentry{Tiger}{i}  
\indexentry{Tiger@Tiger|pageandfn{1}}{i}
```

and the .ind entries of the form

```
\item Tiger, i, 1  
\item Tiger, \pageandfn{1}{i}
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10 pt,twoside]{memoir}  
\chapterstyle{ell}  
\usepackage{imakeidx}  
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\makeindex   
\makeatletter    
\let\latex@roman\@roman   
\makeatother    
\usepackage[russian,greek,english]{babel}  
\makeatletter  
\let\@roman\latex@roman  
\makeatother   

%these next two commands from  
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328833/page-n-footnote-number-in-index-with-texindy  

\newcommand{\pageandfn}[2]{#2n#1}  
\newcommand{\indexfn}[1]{\index{#1@#1|pageandfn{\thefootnote}}}    
\pagestyle{ruled}  
\begin{document}    

\frontmatter   
\chapter{Preface}    
Here's a page and a footnote for the front matter.     Elephant.\index{Elephant} Tiger.\footnote{Tigers are ferocious!\indexfn{Tiger}}\index{Tiger} 

\mainmatter  
\chapter{First things first}  
Here's a page and a footnote for the main matter.\footnote{Cobras are   dangerous!\indexfn{Cobra}} Red panda \index{Red panda} \index{Tiger}  

\indexprologue{\noindent\textbf{Bold} page numbers indicate where a term   is defined; page numbers for entries occuring in a footnote are followed   by an \emph{n} and the footnote number.}  
\printindex  
\end{document}
```

Here's the .idx file:

```
\indexentry{Elephant}{i}  
\indexentry{Tiger}{i}  
\indexentry{Tiger@Tiger|pageandfn{1}}{i}  
\indexentry{Red panda}{1}  
\indexentry{Tiger}{1}  
\indexentry{Cobra@Cobra|pageandfn{1}}{1}  

And here's the .ind file:

\begin{theindex}

  \item Cobra, \pageandfn{1}{1}

  \indexspace

  \item Elephant, i

  \indexspace

  \item Red panda, 1

  \indexspace

  \item Tiger, i, 1  
  \item Tiger, \pageandfn{1}{i}

\end{theindex}
```

Apologies for my cluelessness, and many thanks to the group members for much help over the years!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why `makeindex` makes

```
\indexentry{Tiger}{i}  
\indexentry{Tiger@Tiger|pageandfn{1}}{i}
```

into two seperate entries. I was wondering why the use of `#1@#1` in this macro

```
\newcommand{\indexfn}[1]{\index{#1@#1|pageandfn{\thefootnote}}}
```

Indeed, if we change it to

```
\newcommand{\indexfn}[1]{\index{#1|pageandfn{\thefootnote}}}
```

then `makeindex` folds the entries into a single Tiger.

I normally use `xindy` for indexing, and it will automatically fold both into the same entry (using the original macro definitions), but it will ignore the `|pageandfn{1}` part. We might be able to get it to work with the right `xindy` configuration, but the `|xxx` support in `xindy` is quite limited

Comment: @dderbes remember to hit the check mark to accept the answer