# xindy: var-location-class and ff-ranges; page numbers order problem

Tags: footnotes, indexing, xindy

I am working on a document that contains index items both in the text and in the footnotes. The footnote items are shown differently than the text items. To implement this, I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330291)  answer and I will use the same mwe to illustrate my page numbers order problem.
My desired result is:

> index, 1, 1n1, 2n2, 3, 3n3, 5ff.

I have tried two ways:

1.

For index I have defined a markup-range (f., ff.) and it works fine. The problem is the location class order; the location classes follow each other, means, first all item page numbers from the text (\index) and then all from the footnotes (\indexfn). Is there a possibility to build a "mixed" location class order?

mwe-1.tex

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mwe-style -C utf8]

% test to detect we are in a footnote;
% taken from
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171681/detect-whether-im-in-a-footnote/
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\thefootnote]{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \gdef\infootnote{T}%
  \svfootnote[#1]{#2\gdef\infootnote{F}}%
}
\gdef\infootnote{F}

% write the footnote number if we're in one
% and 0 otherwise
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fnind}{\if T\infootnote
\@currentlabel%
\else 0\fi%
}
\makeatother


% \formatlocc formats the locations as given in the .ind index files
% \formatloc is a wrapper for \formatlocc to permit braces
\newcommand{\formatloc}[1]{\formatlocc #1}
\def\formatlocc #1 #2{%
\ifnumequal{#2}{0}{\hyperpage{#1}}{\hyperpage{#1}n#2}%
}



% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers/20910#20910
\makeatletter
\let\@indexfn\@index
\patchcmd{\@indexfn}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\thepage\space\fnind}{}{}
\let\xindexfn\index
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\newcommand{\indexfn}[2][\imki@jobname]{\xindexfn[#1]{#2|formatloc}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
Some text here\index{index}.%
\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.} %
\newpage
More text here.\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.}%
\newpage
More text here.\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.}%
Some text here\index{index}.%
\newpage
More text.
\newpage
Some text here\index{index}.%
\newpage
Some text here\index{index}.%
\newpage
Some text here\index{index}.%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

mwe-style.xdy

```
;;markup ranges of different length:

(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :close "\,f." :length  1 :ignore-end)
(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :close "\,ff." :length 2 :ignore-end)
(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :sep "--")


;;from:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330291.
;; make xindy and hyperindex work together
;; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80300/how-can-i-convince-hyperref-and-xindy-to-play-together-nicely
;; (the comment by michal.h21)
;; (markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
;; now taken care of by attribute formatloc


(define-attributes (("formatloc")) )
(markup-locref :attr "formatloc" :open "\formatloc{" :close "}")


(define-location-class "pagefn" :var
     ("arabic-numbers" :sep " "  "arabic-numbers"))

(define-location-class-order ("arabic-page-numbers" "pagefn"))

;; End
```

[image]

If I add "-M ff-ranges" I get a correct order but without f., ff. (I believe for the same reason as described below)

2.

I only use \indexfn everywhere, which is possible, because it recognizes whether it is in the footnote or not. The order is correct. The problem here is that I don't know how to define a markup-range for var-location-class. The [documentation](http://www.xindy.org/doc/manual-3.html#ss3.1) says:

> ... building of ranges is currently only allowed for standard classes `:var` and `:min-range-length` must not be used together.

Is there another possibility that I don't see?

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mwe-style -C utf8]

% test to detect we are in a footnote;
% taken from
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171681/detect-whether-im-in-a-footnote/
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\thefootnote]{%
  \stepcounter{footnote}%
  \gdef\infootnote{T}%
  \svfootnote[#1]{#2\gdef\infootnote{F}}%
}
\gdef\infootnote{F}

% write the footnote number if we're in one
% and 0 otherwise
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fnind}{\if T\infootnote
\@currentlabel%
\else 0\fi%
}
\makeatother


% \formatlocc formats the locations as given in the .ind index files
% \formatloc is a wrapper for \formatlocc to permit braces
\newcommand{\formatloc}[1]{\formatlocc #1}
\def\formatlocc #1 #2{%
\ifnumequal{#2}{0}{\hyperpage{#1}}{\hyperpage{#1}n#2}%
}



% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers/20910#20910
\makeatletter
\let\@indexfn\@index
\patchcmd{\@indexfn}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\thepage\space\fnind}{}{}
\let\xindexfn\index
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xindexfn}{\@index}{\@indexfn}{}{}
\newcommand{\indexfn}[2][\imki@jobname]{\xindexfn[#1]{#2|formatloc}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
Some text here\indexfn{index}.%
\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.} %
\newpage
More text here.\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.}%
\newpage
More text here.\footnote{A footnote\indexfn{index}.}%
Some text here\indexfn{index}.%
\newpage
More text.
\newpage
Some text here\indexfn{index}.%
\newpage
Some text here\indexfn{index}.%
\newpage
Some text here\indexfn{index}.%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]